# Draw arc using angles in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have set of values for each angle ranging from 0 to 360 degrees. Now I want to take some co-ordinate on panel as ORIGIN and using a for loop I want to plot the graph based on the angle and its value with respect to the origin.

For example:

```
for(int angle=0 ; angle< 360; angle++){
   graphics.draw(origin, angle, value[angle]);
}
```

I am new to Swings, based on my learning a and searching in internet I found solutions on how to draw arc for given 2 points but in my example I need to draw lines from origin with an angle and length from origin to my point depends on `value[angle]`.

Can someone please provide some pointers on how can we achieve this using Java Swings?

For example the image looks like this. I have input as (Angle , length) -- (0,5), (30,7), (85,4)

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's not exactly an arc, is it? If for angle 0 you have a length of 5 and for angle 30 you have a length of 7, then the two points are not on the same circle. How do you decide which line to draw between them? Your drawing shows an arbitrary meandering line.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes correct, but here I am not planning to draw a circle, just for example I mentioned angles 0,30,85. But I have complete list of values from 0 to 360 and the corresponding lengths. So I just need to draw a line for each degree, so it need not be a circle. Problem is I am not able to find an API that helps me to achieve this. Can you please provide some pointers on how it can be done?

Comment: So a straight line between the point that's on angle 0 and the point that's on angle 1 is good?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Guess you need to draw a line from one point to the next; I don't think you want to draw an arc.

It would be something like that:

```
double x = originx;
double y = originy + value[0]*scale;
for(int angle=1 ; angle< 360; angle++){
    double rad = angle*Math.PI/180.0;
    double x1 = originx + value[i]*scale*Math.cos(rad);
    double y1 = originy + value[i]*scale*Math.sin(rad);
    graphics.drawLine(int)x, (int)y, (int)x1, (int)y1);
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
}
```

UPDATE:

Note that if you've got a Graphics2D, you can first build a Path2D, then draw it on the graphics:

```
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(0, value[0]);
for(int angle=1 ; angle< 360; angle++){
    double rad = angle*Math.PI/180.0;
    path.lineTo(value[i]*Math.cos(rad), value[i]*Math.sin(rad));
}
g2d.translate(originx, originy);
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.draw(path);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you please explainwhy should we use `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` here?

Comment: To convert polar coordinates into cartesian coordinates